# Progress bar under an image slider in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a progress bar under a slider in pure CSS. I have two images in my slider, the bar must be at 50% when the first image is shown and at 100% when the second image is shown.

However I can't display as expected the bar for the second image, the bar won't resize when switching to it (image slider works fine)

Can you help me ?

Thank you ! 
Audrey

```css
    #slider {
     position: relative;    
     width: 100%;          
     height: 400px;       
     overflow: hidden;    
    }

    #images_slider {
     position: absolute;   
     top: 0;              
     left: 0;             
     margin: 0;            
     padding: 0;
        width: 100%;         
     height: 400px; 
    }

    #images_slider li {
     display: flex;      
    }

    #images_slider img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
    }

    #image_gars:target #image_fille { 
     left: -150%; 
    }  

    #banniere #bouton_prev {
     position: absolute;
     left : 0;
     top: 42%;
     border : solid rgba(153,153,153,0.2) 0.1px;
     background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.2);
     width: 25px;
     height: 50px;
     border-top-right-radius: 100px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        z-index: 6;
    }

    .fa.fa-chevron-left {
     position: absolute;
     left : 0;
     top: 45%;
     margin-left: 5px;
     color: white;
     z-index: 4;
    }

    #banniere #bouton_next {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 42%;
     border : solid rgba(153,153,153,0.2) 0.1px;
     background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.2);
     border-top-left-radius: 100px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        width: 25px;
     height: 50px;
     z-index: 6;
    }

    .fa.fa-chevron-right {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 45%;
     color: white;
     margin-right: 5px;
     z-index: 4;
    }

     #ProgressBar {
         width: 100%;
         height: 5px;
         background-color: #A6A6A6;
     }

     #Progress {
        width: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(53,151,183);
        height: 100%;
     }

     #bouton_next:target  #Progress {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
     }
```

```html
    <div id="banniere">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul id="images_slider">
                <li><img src="images/slider/fillepeinture.jpg" alt="Petite fille avec les mains pleine de peinture" id="image_fille"/></li>     
                <li><img src="images/slider/garconmegaphone.jpg" alt="Petit garçon avec un mégaphone" id="image_gars"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <a href="#image_fille" id="bouton_prev"></a>
        <a href="#image_gars" id="bouton_next"></a>

        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div> 

    <div id="ProgressBar">
        <div id="Progress"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you put this code in a Codepen or JSFiddle ?

Comment: Instead of Codepen or JSFiddle why not use stackoverflows code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another stab at this. You were right when you pointed out that the duplicate IDs were a problem. With more than one ID that can be targeted by the anchor, it turns out that neither of them were targeted.

I added a containing div that now carries the triggering ID, and reworked the css for the images and progress divs to use the container's targeted state to switch on and off:

```css
#ProgressBar div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}

#ProgressBar .image_fille {
  width: 50%;
}

#ProgressBar .image_gars {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .image_fille {
  display: block;
}

.container .image_gars {
  display: none;
}

.container:target .image_fille {
  display: none;
}

.container:target .image_gars {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="image_gars">
  <div id="banniere">
    <img class="image_fille" src="" alt="image fille" />
    <img class="image_gars" src="" alt="image gars" />

    <a href="#image_fille" id="bouton_prev">bouton prev</a>
    <a href="#image_gars" id="bouton_next">bouton next</a>
  </div>

  <div id="ProgressBar">
    <div class="image_fille">half progress</div>
    <div class="image_gars">full progress</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, tried to implement it : I had no success in making it works for the past hour. It can work on its own but whenever I try to reunite the image slider and the progress bar it breaks. Plus I have two html elements that share the same ID which feel weird. Any idea ?

Comment: @AudreyGlx i took another look at my answer. you were right, the duplicate IDs were the problem. i've reworked my example to be shaped like your example code, and i think i've got a solution here. i don't think this CSS trick scales well beyond two pictures, and i think you'd want to use javascript if you needed more slides.

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! Indeed, it would be better to use JS but I have to do a project in pure HTML and CSS, and it's hard!
Anyway, you really helped me so thank you very much!